# JAVA - Decipher "DES" encrypted random number

Tags: java, encryption, des

I would like to know how i could decipher a random number DES/CBC-enciphered with a specific Key.

My protocol states the following:
I am sending a KeyNo (eg. 0x00)
After the KeyNo is sent i get a 8byte (DES) random number. This random number is enciphered with the selected key.

My question would be how do i decipher the data i receive, to find the random number using Cipher

Thank you.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15523_01/apirefs.1111/e10696/oracle/security/crypto/core/DES.html ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To decrypt a DES encrypted stream, simply do :

```
Key key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES").generateSecret(new DESKeySpec(bytesOfThe Key)); // bytesOfTheKey should be 8 bytes long
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES");
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
return new CipherInputStream(inputStream, cipher);
```

You may also be interested in the [doFinal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html#doFinal%28java.nio.ByteBuffer,%20java.nio.ByteBuffer%29) method which works on byteBuffers.

Comment: I think i have to generate the key for cipher.init . How do i do that? And i have the enciphered random number with key 00h, the enciphered random number i have it like byte[] enciphered = { 12 A7 2B 8C 6E BB 93 40}

Comment: Is there a way to return the deciphered into an 8 byte array? instead of inputstream

Comment: Im getting the ShortBufferException `Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.ShortBufferException: Output buffer is null
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.SunJCE_f.b(DashoA13*..)
 at com.sun.crypto.provider.DESCipher.engineDoFinal(DashoA13*..)
 at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(DashoA13*..)` this is what i have done tell me if its wrong: `  cipher.doFinal(INPUT_ENCIPHERED, 0, 8, output);
  System.out.println("OUTPUT: "+output.length);` where byte[] INPUT_ENCIPHERED = enciphered input and output is defined as byte[] output;